# How to store the flutter message data message on dart side

Tags: firebase, flutter

As document said when handle the background message.

> Since the background handler runs in its own isolate outside your applications context, it is not possible to update application state or execute any UI impacting logic. You can however perform logic such as HTTP requests, IO operations (updating local storage), communicate with other plugins etc.

The part of background handler code from document.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

What' the way to execute the IO operations (updating local storage)?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to store data locally.

One example is using the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin.

You can write to `shared_preferences` when you receive the notification like this:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('messageId', message.messageId);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

The code above writes the `messageId` to `shared_preferences` when a message is received from the background.

Comment: Can you help me with this: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
my code is same as your code but it can't get all third party dependencies.

Comment: Try running restarting your app, then run`flutter clean` && `flutter pub get` and then run the app.